# Can we access twig inner property on construction?

Tags: twig

Let's say I'm constructing a Twig object and I want to access an inner property defined previously:

```
{% set my_object = 
  default_width: 12,
  default_height: default_width * 2
%}
```

This throws a `Variable "default_width" does not exist` error, which make sense since the object was not entirely declared yet but is there a way to make this work without two instructions?

Comment: Well, there's no variable `default_width` in the given scope. Also, why not declare this in your controller? That does not look like something you should do in a template

Comment: I'm not using a controller for two reasons: to use twig to make specifications for objects that'll by reused in many other templates and to also learn a little bit more about the language.

Comment: First reason makes no sense, that's why you can define/add globals in twig or  you change your controller to always return a default `my_object`. But no, you can't oneline what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior isn't possible, the best way to do it is to declare a variable before the construction and reusing it here.